# Django: How to decode the url to get the variable value?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm trying to do django api.

Here is the code in urls.py

```
url(r'^edit/(?P<name>[\w-]+)/$', UpdateView.as_view(), name="update")
```

views.py

```
class UpdateView(RetrieveUpdateView):
     queryset = Book.objects.all()
     serializer_class = BookUpdateSerializer
     lookup_field = "name"
```

The `name` variable might include '|' symbol.

When I open URL `127.0.0.1:8000/api/edit/ABCD|1234` in my browser, where `ABCD|1234` is the variable `name`, the url will automatically encode it, and it becomes `127.0.0.1:8000/api/edit/ABCD%7C1234`.

It can't find this name from my database.
How can I decode it and retrieve data from my database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django will decode the url for you. When you access `self.kwargs['name']`, it will be `'ABCD|1234'`, not `'ABCD%7C1234'`.

However, you have a separate issue. Your current regex group `[\w-]+` will only match upper case A-Z, lowercase a-z, digits 0-9, underscore `_` and hyphen `-`. You'll have to change this if you want to match characters like `|`.

You could simply add `|` to the group:

```
# put | before - otherwise you have to escape hypen with \-
url(r'^edit/(?P<name>[\w|-]+)/$', UpdateView.as_view(), name="update")
```

Or, if there are lots of other character you want to add to the group, you could match anything except forward slashes with:

```
url(r'^edit/(?P<name>[^/]+)/$', UpdateView.as_view(), name="update")
```

Comment: I suggest to simply add the `|` in the list of allowed characters : `r'^edit/(?P<name>[\w|-]+)/$'`

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helped me.